# Counting the number of falses before a true in an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I am trying to count the number of falses before each true in an ArrayList in Java.

For example, if I have [true, false, false, true, true]
I would get [0,2,0]

and if a false at the end of the list is not followed by a true, it would not count

so if I have [false, true, false, false]
I would get [1]

I tried this:

```
int incorrect_attempts = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> falses_before_a_true = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0;i<=attempts_list.size()-1;i++){
            if (attempts_list.get(i).equals("false"))
                incorrect_attempts++;
            else
                falses_before_a_true.add(incorrect_attempts);


        }
```

but I would get [1, 1, 1] for [false, true, true, true] which should return [1,0,0]

I think I should reset the incorrect_attempts counter when there are two consecutive trues, but not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok! is that a wish or have u written some code as well?

Comment: Thanks for the note, @JunedAhsan. I added the code I'm trying to fix.

Comment: caught your bug...check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `incorrect_attempts` to 0 when you get a true. So change this:

```
        else
            falses_before_a_true.add(incorrect_attempts);
```

to

```
    else {
        falses_before_a_true.add(incorrect_attempts);
        incorrect_attempts = 0;
    }
```